# GWT SuperDevMode parameters in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I'm currently working on trying to get an existing Eclipse project built with Java EE and GWT to develop and run in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm trying to get SuperDevMode up and running but as soon as I try to pass into the DevMode parameter `-src`, the output gives me
`Unknown argument: -src`.

I've checked `Use Super Dev Mode` in the `Run/Debug Configurations` but I can't think of anything else that might get this to work. Has anyone been able to get SuperDevMode parameters working in Intellij?

[image: Output of console]

Thanks!

Comment: The error ouptut does not list `-src` parameter among possible ones. Make sure you are using compatible GWT version.

Comment: I have version 2.8.0 installed (project required) and I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Steps (GWT >= 2.7.0)

1. Run -> Edit Configurations -> Create an Application
2. Set Main class com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer
3. Program Arguments:
   -src src/main/java -launcherDir {%PATH_TO_YOUR_CLIENT_PROJECT}/src/main/webapp {%MODULE1 %MODULE2}

EX: -src src/main/java -launcherDir /home/santran/ionoff/client/src/main/webapp net.ionoff.center.IApp

(IApp.gwt.xml is in package net.ionoff.center)

4. Working directory: Path to your project
   (Ex: /home/santran/ionoff/client)
5. Apply -> close
6. Add your project to App server (tomcat or jetty ...)
7. Start app server, start your new Application in IntelliJ