# how to debug gwt with super dev (intellij)

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt

Using IDEA 2018.3 ide ultimate, from windows 10, I cannot specify which gwt modules to load in the debug configuration, in order to debug client side java, with super dev plugin in chrome browser, the message is "no gwt modules found".

From chrome pressing the "debug in jet idea" button in the plugin does seem indeed to connect to the ide.

The project was imported from eclipse, how can I activate which gwt modules ?

[intellij ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm89U.png)

Answer (score 2):

What is this Chrome plugin you are talking about ? I use IntelliJ for GWT, and debugging works fine. But I never installed any plugin for Chrome. I just run from IntelliJ, and I can set breakpoints in IntelliJ and in Chrome Developer tools.

1. Does your webapp actually runs/works when starting from IntelliJ
2. Can you set breakpoints in Chrome developer tools and do these get triggered ?

I looked at your screenshot, this is identical to my settings.

Comment: actually I had a slew of problems see : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001803699-how-to-debug-gwt-with-super-dev

Comment: For GWT > 2.7, you can look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624617/gwt-superdevmode-parameters-in-intellij-idea/51665577#51665577